# Bug on StackOverflow careers page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On this page: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/google/74597

1) The [Example](http://code.google.com/u/@VxdTRlxUDhBEXAh8/) link provided is a 404

2) If importing this project list: `code.google.com/u/114362340915143706279`: then the imported link decodes apostrophe's incorrectly: e.g. API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, these two issues should be resolved.